# How to get current java version inside pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

how can we access current installed java version inside pom.xml. and set it into maven properties.
when we are changing the java version frequently is there any way to retrieve it in maven properties.

i want to do something like this

```
<project>
...
 <properties>
    <installedJava>${currentJavaVersion}</installedJava>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

i saw some answeres which suggest to know java version using `mvn -version` command. but it give us version in  command shell not in maven at build time.

**And further i also want to know** can we retrieve the major version only. like "17" from "17.0.6"

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @Thorbjørn i want to activate a profile based on installed java major version.

Comment: So your code base behaves differently for different versions of Java?  How come you chose that approach?

Comment: @Thorbjørn actually i want the build process to behave differently for java's. im building my code with all the kind's of java's by frequently switching them. and based on java's we pass different jvmparams and setting properties and switching plugins etc.

Comment: jvmparams, plugins and properties?  To compile your code??  Or for testing?

Comment: @Thorbjørn majorly for testing.

Comment: Then it is not building, it is testing.  I don’t think this will end in a maintainable solution. Consider reworking it into a maven module per test platform (sharing whatever is needed).

Comment: @Thorbjørn we are building our module also with different properties per java version. and also according to java version we are passing those properties into project and creating some properties there. and creating multiple builds having different source and target combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java built-in System property `java.version`

Reference https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html